# border-left height in css

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b7uaoj2/2/) and I am trying to copy as it is as shown in this [image](https://s9.postimg.org/9iyiyr99r/border-left_height.png). At this moment, I am able to put borders across an image but for some reasons I am not able to increase the height of border-left. I am pretty sure it will done through CSS selectors but not sure how. The CSS which I have used to put the borders across an image is:

```
.helmet-image1
{
position: relative;
left: 20px;
border-left: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
border-right: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
border-top: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by height of border? Please explain more

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/9b7uaoj2/3/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by putting a container outside your image, and setting the container height.

```
.container {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.helmet-image1
{  
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

<div class="container">
    <img class="helmet-image1" 
    src="https://s24.postimg.org/m3yekb9n9/i_Stock-516143705.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the image in an element, you can use borders on the parent and pseudo elements of that parent element to fake a border that is a different height than the parent/image.

You can use `bottom` to control the height, or replace bottom with `height` and use something like `height: calc(100% + 100px);`

```css
div
{ 
position: relative;
left: 20px;
border-right: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
border-top: 2px solid rgb(254, 91, 31);
display: inline-block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}


div::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: -100px;
  width: 2px;
  background: rgb(254,91,31);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="helmet-image1" src="https://s24.postimg.org/m3yekb9n9/i_Stock-
516143705.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do this without using div (without putting image class inside div) ?

Comment: no, you can't do it with just a border unless part of the image is transparent or something. pseudo elements don't work with images, so you have to apply them to standard elements.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `box-shadow` on img tag eventually:

```css
img {
  padding: 5px;/*optionnal */
  vertical-align: top;/*optionnal */
  box-shadow: -2px -2px rgb(254, 91, 31), 0 171px white, -2px 170px rgb(254, 91, 31), 2px -2px rgb(254, 91, 31), 2px -1px rgb(254, 91, 31), 0px -2px rgb(254, 91, 31);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0/*optionnal */
}

/* demo purpose for small snippet */ 
body {min-height:400px;}
```

```html
<img class="helmet-image1" src="https://s24.postimg.org/m3yekb9n9/i_Stock-
516143705.png">
<br/> text to test
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b7uaoj2/15/